# Dump hidden (or minimized) X11 window

Tags: x11, capture

I'd like to dump the contents of an X window. Like this:

xwd -id  | convert - capture.png

... which works quite well as long as the target window is not hidden (totally or partially behind other windows) or minimized.

Any idea on how to do this?

I guess we somehow have to send a "repaint" signal to the hidden window and then capture its response or something... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an objection to bringing it to the front first?

If not, you can use a tool like [wmctrl](http://www.sweb.cz/tripie/utils/wmctrl/) to bring the window to the front (and maximize it, etc), use xwd to capture it, then send it back to where it came from with wmctrl.